# python tkinter how to stop decimals being so long

Tags: python, tkinter

I’m creating a calculator right now and when I type in the entry or just even the shell, which uses eval like my calculator, 3-0.1 is not 2.9 like a normal calculator. It gives you very long numbers like 2.8999999999. How to fix this and make it rounded always?

Comment: How are you displaying the value? Are you explicitly setting the contents of an `Entry` or `Label`? Calling `var.set(str(n))` on a `StringVar`? Calling `var.set(n)` on a `DoubleVar`? …?

Comment: If you're doing any of the things that explicitly convert to a string, you should use string formatting to specify exactly the format you want to display, as in [Bob's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50124092/908494). If you're using a `DoubleVar` and letting Tcl/Tk do the formatting for you, it's a bit trickier.

Comment: The reason why these numbers are not quite what you would expect is because of [floating point error](https://0.30000000000000004.com). If you want to do "more correct" numerical computations, have a look at Python's [`decimal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html) and [`fractions`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fractions.html) libraries.

Answer (score 1):

You should use string formatting for output of your program:

https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/string.html#format-string-syntax

I.e.

```
float_result = 3 - 0.1
formatted_to_two_decimal_places = '{:.2f}'.format(float_result)
# or you can do ... = f'{float_result:.2f}' in python 3.6+
print(formatted_to_two_decimal_places)
```

Comment: @abarnert Python used to pride itself on having only one obvious way of doing any particular thing. How many ways are there now of doing string formatting?

Comment: @MarkRansom The `format` function is the one obvious way to format a single value. That's not the same thing as combine multiple formatted values and static text, so why should it be the same function?

Comment: @MarkRansom Unless you're asking about f-strings vs. `str.format`. `str.format` is there for backward compatibility, because nobody thought of a good design back in 2006, but that doesn't make them a good choice for new code; f-strings are the one obvious way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can round your output using the `round()` function.

Usage: `round(number, no. of decimal places)`

Eg:

```
num1 = 1/3
num2 = round(num1, 2)  # num2 would be 0.33

num3 = 2/3
num4 = round(num3, 3)  # num4 would be 0.667
```